# DualBoot Laptop Moving Ubuntu Install Probably a repeat question

Tags: dual-boot, usb

So I have a laptop set up with a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.1

I set this up myself and am happy with the set up.

However, I am thinking that maybe I should move the Ubuntu install from the laptop built in drive to a 1 TB USB drive. This will

a) give me a lot more space for the Ubuntu Install

b) release the disk space taken up by the Ubuntu install on my laptop

c) enable me to manage my drives better

I would like to keep the dual boot functionality but with the Ubuntu running off the USB drive

Problem one

How do I actually tell which of the drives listed (without a letter) is my Ubuntu install.
This is listed all over the place on "t'web" but nothing definitive about identifying

Problem 2

How do I then move the Ubuntu Install to the USB drive lock stock and keep the functionality of the dual boot
Can I do it from Windows portion of dual boot or do I need to be on the Ubuntu portion?

Comment: If you installed it why do you not know the version of Ubuntu? It could be 20.10 or 20.04

Comment: Apologies have added version

Although I would have thought that the version was immaterial as it is the process I am interested in.  Yes it may be slightly different between versions but the process is what I am after.